# What is the equivalent of factory-method="aspectOf" for a @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-bean

What is the equivalent of

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.xxx.MyClass" factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

when using a [Spring 4 @Bean-annotated method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)?

Comment: How about the same... `MyClass.aspectOf()`...

Comment: @Steve have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Fede Sorry, no - I didn't need to do it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is no annotation for the factory method, but you can use the @Configuration and @Bean annotations

```
@Configuration
public class MyClass {

    @Bean
    public MyClass myObject() {
        return MyStaticFactory.getObject();
    }

}
```

MyStaticFactory does not require any Spring annotations.

Answer (score -1):

Use `@Configurable` with `<context:spring-configured>`

Comment: This is not an answer, please be more specific and add some explanation.